# PHP display results equivalent to comma separated values in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database structure say this:

table: advertisements

```
ad_id  | ad_memberships
   1   | 1,2
   2   | 1,2,3
   3   | 1,3
   4   | 2,3
```

table: memberships

```
mbs_id | mbs_color
   1   | red
   2   | yellow
   3   | green
```

I want to display the colors for the values that are there in `ad_memberships` field. This field contains the IDs from `memberships` tables which is `mbs_id`. Now since `ad_memberships` contains 1,2 then the red and yellow color should be displayed. If it contains 1,3 or 2,3 or 1,2,3 then red, green or yellow, green or red, yellow, green colors should be displayed respectively. Now, I know and I understand that I should be normalizing the database and not using a comma separated values but here in my case I need to go like this only. So the problem is I am not being able to execute this. I somehow managed to get this far:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color) FROM advertisements
                            INNER JOIN memberships ON FIND_IN_SET(memberships.mbs_id, advertisements.ad_memberships)
                            LEFT JOIN ads_category ON advertisements.ad_category = ads_category.ac_id
                            WHERE ad_credits >= ac_credits AND ad_category = :cat AND ad_status = 'active'
                            GROUP BY advertisements.ad_id
```

You can see the example of the above code here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/746169/3 but my version of code is given above and in the code below. And this is what I exactly want https://prnt.sc/hvj91s.

**PROBLEM :** 
Now the problem is that when I run the following code all I get is just one color throughout that is color for `mbs_id` 1. Say, I get red for all the field. I want all the colors to be displayed for which the values are there in the database field `ad_memberships`. I made it extremely clear now please help me guys. Stuck in this for too long now.

Code

```
<div class="ads-container">
  <?php
    $cat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ads_category");
    $cat-> execute();

    $i = 0;
    while($s = $cat->fetch()){
      $ads = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color) FROM advertisements
                            INNER JOIN memberships ON FIND_IN_SET(memberships.mbs_id, advertisements.ad_memberships)
                            LEFT JOIN ads_category ON advertisements.ad_category = ads_category.ac_id
                            WHERE ad_credits >= ac_credits AND ad_category = :cat AND ad_status = 'active'
                            GROUP BY advertisements.ad_id");
      $ads-> bindValue(':cat', $s['ac_id']);
      $ads-> execute();

      while($a = $ads->fetch()){ extract($a); 
  ?>
      <div class="" <?php if($i++ != 0){ echo "style='margin-top: 30px'"; } ?>>
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $ac_category; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="adcover">
          <div class="ad-title">
            <a href="surf.php?ad=<?php echo $ad_id; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $ad_title; ?></a>
          </div>
          <div class="ad-footer-two">
            <span class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $mbs_color; ?>; margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 5px"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution is to normalize.. Besides `INNER JOIN memberships ON FIND_IN_SET(memberships.mbs_id, advertisements.ad_memberships)` can never use indexes.. so it your tables grow  in records your query will be slower... CSV in databases only cause you problems what if you need to COUNT things or get a unique list..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am thinking a way to normalize this. Suggest me a way if you can please.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I understand but here for now I do not need to count the things or get any unique list ever. All I need is to display the respective colors.

Comment: @RaymondNijland these comma separated values comes from checkboxes so I cannot normalize them. Please help if you can with either normalizing or by just letting me know how in my case I can fetch colors here.

Comment: Wasn't this deleted?

Comment: @Strawberry and yes I nearly cracked the tail. Now I am posting a new question for this same issue but with a different problem as I am very close now.

Comment: Any time you have `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` in the same query, you can be sure that you're heading down the wrong path. A good rule-of-thumb is NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: And as you know, normalisation is the essential first step here. The rest is noise.

Comment: @Strawberry the problem is solved in the new question I asked. Thanks for your time :)