# PHP display comma separated GROUP_CONCAT values separately

Tags: php, foreach

This question is with reference to my previous question posted here [PHP display results equivalent to comma separated values in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080764/php-display-results-equivalent-to-comma-separated-values-in-the-database?noredirect=1#comment83135885_48080764).
I nearly solved the problem. Now I am stuck somewhere else which if solved my issue will be solved.

**The problem is:**
Please have a look at this code first

```
<div class="ads-container">
  <?php
    $cat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ads_category");
    $cat-> execute();

    $i = 0;
    while($s = $cat->fetch()){
      $ads = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color) FROM advertisements
                            INNER JOIN memberships ON FIND_IN_SET(memberships.mbs_id, advertisements.ad_memberships)
                            LEFT JOIN ads_category ON advertisements.ad_category = ads_category.ac_id
                            WHERE ad_credits >= ac_credits AND ad_category = :cat AND ad_status = 'active'
                            GROUP BY advertisements.ad_id");
      $ads-> bindValue(':cat', $s['ac_id']);
      $ads-> execute();

      while($a = $ads->fetch()){ extract($a); 
  ?>
      <div class="" <?php if($i++ != 0){ echo "style='margin-top: 30px'"; } ?>>
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $ac_category; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="adcover">
          <div class="ad-title">
            <a href="surf.php?ad=<?php echo $ad_id; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $ad_title; ?></a>
          </div>
          <div class="ad-footer-two"> <?php echo $a['GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color)']; // this is giving me the values comma separated perfectly ?>
            <span class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $mbs_color; ?>; margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 5px"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I echo `<?php echo $a['GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color)']; ?>` I get the comma separed color values perfectly. But I want to display it as a color not as a word in `<span class="membership-incdicator"></span>` as exactly as in https://prnt.sc/hvj91s. So, how can I do that? Do I have to use `foreach()` function here? If yes then please tell me how to write that code. If not, then please tell me how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole thing looks very messy, but explode the list and loop:

```
$mbs_colors = explode(',', $a['GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color)']);

foreach($mbs_colors as $color) {
    echo '<span class="membership-indicator" style="background: ' . $color . '; margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 5px"></span>';
}
```

Also, you can use an alias: `SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(memberships.mbs_color) AS colors` and then use: `$a['colors']`.

This does beg the question; why `GROUP_CONCAT` then?  I'm not sure but there must be a better query.

Comment: Thanks.. this solved but the colors are over laping one on top of the other... I want it to appear side by side with a margin-left of say 15px.

Comment: At best, `SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT...` will return an indeterminate result. At worst, that indeterminate result will be misleadingly erroneous.